# Outdoor party lights keep burning fuses

Tags: lighting

I just bought several strings of lights.  At first they were fine, but then they keep popping fuses.  The lights say they are 60 amps.  Can I replace the fuse with higher amp or what do I have to do to keep them running?

Comment: 60A?!  Do you mean 60W?  A 60A string of lights would be *blinding*!

Comment: Hmm, these are small indoor/outdoor party light strings,  maybe 60 watts?  I guess I misread

Comment: Yeah, I'd double check the box and report back what it actually says :)

Comment: I think we can safely exclude 60A unless the wires are the size f your thumb and the plug the size of your fist.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it is not safe to replace the fuse with a higher amp fuse. If the fuse is 15 amps, that means the wiring can handle 15 amps. If you allow too much current over too little wire, things get hot, fast. You definitely don't want an electrical fire. So let's troubleshoot the problem instead...

If you're running a lot of those strings and there's other stuff on the circuit (e.g. a fridge or air conditioner) you might be overdrawing and tripping the fuse.

1. What else goes out when the lights go out?
2. How many strings of lights are you linking?
3. How many amps is the fuse that keeps blowing?

Comment: I think you are right...  I probably have too many connected together.  Thanks for the info on fuses.  Good to know.

Comment: @deb when you find a answer that is helpful up vote it . This provides recognition to everyone that this person was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You never, never, ever "replace a fuse with a bigger one to stop it from blowing!"  That's how you start fires. The correct approach is to solve the problem that is causing them to blow.

Even resetting a circuit breaker over and over can overload a wire and start a fire.   These devices are not to annoy you, they are to protect you.

Typically fuses in string lights use a fuze size that is appropriate for protecting *the wires in the string lights*.  That is the limiting factor to how many strings of this same type you can connect nose to tail. Typically the package box will tell you the limit.

You don't need to connect them all nose to tail.  For instance you can connect them in a star fashion with several chains starting from a power strip.